# How to solve a complex polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, symbolic-computation

1. Solve:
   $$ z^3 - 3z^2 + 6z - 4 = 0$$

How do I solve this?

Can I do it by basically letting $ z = x + iy$ such that $ i = \sqrt{-1}$ and $ x, y \in \mathbf R $ and then substitute that into the equation and get a crazy long equation? If I did that I suspect I wouldn't be able to decipher the imaginary part of the equation.

Or should I change it to one of the forms below:

$$ z^n = r^n \mathbf{cis} n \theta $$
$$ z^n = r^n e^{n\theta i} $$

And then plug that into the equation? I did that. But it looked unsolvable. I'm so confused.

Comment: First look for integer roots. You should be able to find one pretty fast. Then you're left with a quadratic equation.

Comment: If in an other example, you can't find a obvious root then remember that every polynomial with odd degree has a real root (thanks to the intermediate value theorem) and there is a method due to Cardano for polynomial of degree 3 in order to get this root.

Comment: I did try that method @DanielFischer - and couldn't find a root.

Comment: The rational root theorem says the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4$.  Only six to check.

Answer (score 5):

Since complex number field $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, every polynomials with complex coefficients have linear polynomial decomposition. In this case, it's
$$
z^3 - 3z^2 + 6z - 4 = (z - 1)(z - 1 + \sqrt{3}i)(z - 1 - \sqrt{3}i).
$$
So you can see the solution of the equation easily from this representation.

One way to find out such decomposition is simply put
$$ 
z^3 - 3z^2 + 6z - 4 = c(z - \alpha)(z - \beta)(z - \gamma)
$$
to find out the coefficients by equating coefficients of power of $z$.

Answer (score 3):

If you substitute in $z=x+iy$ the real and imaginary parts are each cubics-you just sort out the terms that have a factor $i$ for the imaginary part and you have a real equation.  But as Daniel Fischer says, there is an easier approach here.  To see what happens, we have $$(x+iy)^3-3(x+iy)^2+6(x+iy)-4=0\\x^3+3ix^2y-3xy^2-iy^3-3x^2-6ixy+3y^2+6x+6iy-4=0\\x^3-3xy^2-3x^2+3y^2+6x-4=0\\3x^2y-y^3-6xy+6y=0$$ where the second came from the imaginary part.  It is no worse than the real part, which is the next to last line.

Answer (score 3):

$z=x+1$ $\Longrightarrow$ $x^{3}+3x=0$

$\therefore$ $x=0$ , $\pm\sqrt{3}i$

$\therefore$ $z=1$ , $1\pm\sqrt{3}i$

Comment: I wonder why my answer is not useful.
Mine is just substitution.
If elementary, is it not useful?

Comment: I think this is one way to solve this. More generally, [this kind of reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic) always works in every cubic equation.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is just try to guest a root of the polynomial first. In this case, for

$$p(z) = z^3 - 3z^2 + 6z - 4,$$
we have that $p(1) = 0$.

Therefore, you can factorize it further and get
$$z^3 - 3z^2 + 6z - 4 = (z-1)(z^2 - 2z + 4)$$

$$= (z-1)((z-1)^2 + 3).$$

Their roots are just $$z_{1} = 1, \hspace{10pt}z_{2} = 1 + i\sqrt{3}, \hspace{10pt}z_{3} = 1 - i\sqrt{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

@Petch Puttichai , after we've guessed the root say $p(1)$, how do we find the other factors , is it that we divide the polynomial with first factor , are there any other methods ?

For example if I have a polynomial of $z^4+z^3+... $ after we find the first root by guessing, how to get the other polynomial which I think should be of the form $z^3+z^2+...$.

Thanks for all your help.

Arif

Comment: Yes, we divide the polynomial with the term that we've just got. I'm not sure if there is any easier way...