# Finding roots of $z^3+z+1=0$, complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

In particular i know how to solve $z^n=1$, for complex value $z$.

In my recent question, [Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^3+x+1}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021191/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac1x3x1dx)
I have problem with finding zeros of denominator. $i.e$, poles of integrand.

Is there some systematic way of solving some polynomials for complex equation? 
$i.e$ $a^nz_n + \cdots +a_0=0$.

Is it too broad? I know that for real $x$ there is some forumla for $n=2,3,4$. 
although, $n=2$ is usual roots formula learned in high school.

Typical way to solve $z^3+z+1=0$ is enough for me at this moment, but i want to know some general procedure of obtaining solutions for complex polynomials.

Any references or links are welcome!

Comment: There are many ways to find roots by what we call "iterative methods". There are various levels of sophistication of iterative methods; I suggest you Google that. As you say there is no formula for polynomials of order 5 or above. It has even been proven that no such formula can possibly exist (group theory is a wonderful thing). I cannot immediately bring to mind anything other than iterative methods at this moment.

Comment: See whether this link helps you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484906/how-to-solve-a-complex-polynomial

Comment: _Lagrange-Burman Inversion_ comes to mind. It lets you find the roots as a power series. I am not sure if it could be possible to compute exact values as integrand or in similar situations but at least it will give you another method to estimate roots.

Answer (score 1):

This polynomial is irreducible in the field of Rationals. Therefore, as pointed out in the comment, we have to use numerical methods to get approximate solution. Exact solution using [Cardano's method](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekkreith/tutorials/sample.lesson/cardano.html) is possible, but is quite tedious.